# How to check if the last string character equals '*' in Bash?

Tags: string, bash

I need to check if a path contains the '*' character as last digit.

My approach:

```sh
length=${#filename}
((filename--))
#use substring to get the last character
if [ ${img:$length:1} == "*"] ;then
   echo "yes"
fi
```

This returns the *`[: too many arguments`* error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
[ "${filename:$length:1}" == "*" ] && echo yes
```

In your post, there was no space between `"*"` and `]`.  This confuses bash.  If a statement begins with `[`, bash insists that its last argument be `]`.  Without the space, the last argument is `"*"]` which, after quote removal, becomes `*]` which is not `]`.

Putting it all together:

```
length=${#filename}
((length--))
[ "${filename:$length:1}" == "*" ] && echo yes
```

**MORE:**  As per the comments below, the three lines above can be simplified to:

```
[ "${filename: -1}" == "*" ] && echo yes
```

The `-1` is shorthand for getting the last character.  Another possibility is:

```
[[ $filename = *\* ]] && echo yes
```

This uses bash's more powerful conditional test `[[`.  The above sees if `$filename` is matches the glob pattern `*\*` where the first star means "zero or more of any character" and the last two characters, `\*`, mean a literal star character.  Thus, the above tests for whether filename ends with a literal `*`.  Another solution to this problem using `[[` can be found in @broslow's answer.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me! The error was caused by the missing quotes, and  the square bracket mistake you explained!

Comment: +1; two more things worth mentioning: (a) using `[[...]]` over `[...]` is generally preferred in bash (fewer surprises, more features) and (b) it's easier to get the last character with `${filename: -1}` (or, even easier, as @chepner suggests, use `$filename == *\*`).

Comment: Totally agree mklement0's advice.

Answer (score 11):

Just use regex

```
if [[ "$filename" =~ '*'$ ]]; then 
  echo "yes"
fi
```

Couple of issues in your syntax.

- You need a space before the last `]`
- Make sure to quote variables inside single brackets
- `${variable:${#variable}:1}` won't return any characters, `${variable:$((${#variable}-1))}` should work (note though the 1 length at the end is redundant)

Comment: You can also use pattern matching: `[[ $filename = *\* ]]`. Which you choose is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Why use double quotes inside double [[ ]]? By the way, why use "if; then fi" sintax while using double [[ ]] ?